# Mongo shell timeout

Tags: mongodb

I am using Mongo shell in order to work with my databases, I'm trying to export some files from my DB when I try to do that I get the following error:

```
Failed: WSARecv tcp localhost:port: i/o timeout
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain more in your question what you are actually doing. You might just consider looking into connectivity problems with the node you are connecting to as well.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do:

mongoexport --host <host_ip><port>
-u jimmy --password kimmel --db <db_name> --collection <collection_name> --query {<query>} --out <nameOfFile>.json

it starts export but then it disconnwects and giving me that error message.